# Migrate a resource from Helm to Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm

We're in the process of removing Helm from our IAC setup and switching to using just Terraform.  Our system is currently running live in production so simply deleting all the Helm charts and re-deploying with Terraform is not an option as the system must maintain uptime.

Our original idea was to:

1. Use a tool like [k2tf](https://github.com/sl1pm4t/k2tf) to convert the Helm yamls to Terraform config
2. Run `tf import ...` to import the existing k8s resource in Terraform state
3. Run `tf apply` to allow Terraform to strip off any attached Helm metadata such as labels/annotations
4. Update the helm chart to no longer include the resource and deploy it

Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to work as step 4 still deletes the resource. We had hoped that the Helm labels/annotations cleaned up in step 3 would make Helm think it doesn't own the resource anymore and thus not delete it, but it seems the Helm release still maintained some knowledge of it.

Any ideas on how this could be done? I know there are ways to delete a Helm chart a leave the resources in place but as mentioned this isn't really an option for us. We want to slowly migrate resources out of the Helm chart. Is there someway to explicitly tell Helm to "disown" a resource?

Comment: A word of warning, managing k8s resources via TF is pretty clunky compared to helm, kustomize, or other systems specifically designed for managing k8s resources.. Helm stores revision information in k8s secrets. You can likely delete these secrets manually.

Comment: @jordanm we made the decision to switch from Helm to TF recently. It seems more stable now than it has been and it didn't make sense to maintain 2 IAC technologies hence why we're removing Helm. I'm aware Helm stores the state in secrets, but I think it's one secret per chart, not one secret per resource, hence it is only possible to drop the whole chart, not an individual resource.

Comment: To further clarify @jordanm comment given the reply above: Helm is not infrastructure as code. Helm is a package/application deployment manager for k8s. The most common use case is TF and Helm in conjunction, and not one versus the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging through the docs, I found the `"helm.sh/resource-policy": keep` annotation: https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#tell-helm-not-to-uninstall-a-resource

By applying this to a resource it means Helm won't delete it even if you run a `helm upgrade` to a chart version with the resource removed.

So our strategy for migrating a resource from Helm to TF goes as follows:

1. Attach the `"helm.sh/resource-policy": keep` annotation to the desired resource then release and deploy the Helm chart.
2. Remove the resource description from the Helm chart and release and deploy again.
3. Write the terraform config for that resource (using [k2tf](https://github.com/sl1pm4t/k2tf) from the original yaml if appropriate)
4. Run `tf import ...` on the now orphaned k8s resource
5. Run `tf apply` to bring everything up to date